# how to prove independency of 2 variables

Tags: independence, uniform-distribution

> The variable $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over $$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|+|y|\le1\}.$$ Let $$A=X-Y,B=X+Y.$$
> Are $A$ and $B$ independent?

I tried to prove $F(AB)=F(A)F(B)$, I tried to find the joint function of $AB$ through changing variables. $X=(A-B)/2$ and $Y=(A+B)/2$ and got that the joint function is $F(AB)=C/2$. How do I continue from here? How can I find the marginal functions to check if the equation is correct?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I have edited your question. See if that is indeed what you meant.